# How to use IMultiValueConverter with a separate list in an Image control?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using `ValueToVisibilityConverter : IMultiValueConverter` in a `ControlTemplate` which has an `Image` and a `ComboBox`. The `ComboBox` is bound to a list of strings.
And `ValueToVisibilityConverter` is applied on the image with `MultiBinding` to the `ComboBox` properties `SelectedText` and `Text`.

I want to check that `SelectedText`/`Text` exists in a list or not, if not then show the image.
It is working fine with the list which is bound to the `ComboBox` but I have to check the value in another list. Can anyone please let me how to do this?

My code is:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="ChannelGroupControlTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type igEditors:XamTextEditor}">
    <Microsoft_Windows_Themes:ListBoxChrome x:Name="BorderContainer">
      <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="/Sample;component/Resources/Images/ErrorProvider.png" ToolTip="{l:Localize This item is not found in the system}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
               Focusable="False" VerticalAlignment="Center">
          <Image.Visibility>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ValueToVisibilityConverter}" >
              <Binding ElementName="comboBox" Path="SelectedValue"/>
              <Binding ElementName="comboBox" Path="Text"/>
            </MultiBinding>
          </Image.Visibility>
        </Image>
        <ComboBox Name="comboBox"
                      IsEditable="True"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Source={x:Static BasicEditors:DSTChannelGroupViewModel.TypeValues}}"
                                               Grid.Column="1" Margin="0" Padding="1" BorderThickness="0" Background="Transparent"/>
      </Grid>
    </Microsoft_Windows_Themes:ListBoxChrome>
  </ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: I have to check the SelectedText in an other list of string named AllTypeValues. How to use this list in converter to do the same?

Comment: Where is that other list ? You are trying to solve this problem in the View, but maybe it should be the ViewModel's responsability to do the processing ?

Answer (score 0):

Multi Converter unnecessary here,  you should only the value.

1. you can binding to SelectedValue and check in converter if value is nothing - null.
2. you can use Trigger on SelectedIndex property, then set image to visible.

Here's the second way:

```
<Image x:Name="image" Grid.Column="0" Source="/Avl.OneParam.UI.Core;component/Resources/Images/ErrorProvider.png" 
       ToolTip="{l:Localize This item is not found in the system}" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
       Focusable="False" VerticalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Hidden" />
```

and add this trigger to ControlTemplate:

```
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=comboBox, Path=SelectedIndex}" Value="-1">
        <Setter TargetName="image" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
    </DataTrigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

Comment: Thanks guys for your valueable replies.. :)

Comment: Is there any approch to add a simple list in multibinding or only a Dependancy property can be bind??

Comment: This is a new question, the answer is: you can put any property in Binding expression, But the element of the set the binding Must be DP.